# PERMISSION_DENIED (rules set for wrong database product)

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

Database rules:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

Storage rules:

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

And it says `Anyone with your database reference will be able to read or write to your database`

Error i am getting:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: PERMISSION_DENIED: Permission denied
    at firebase.js:1
    at exceptionGuard (firebase.js:1)
    at e.callOnCompleteCallback (firebase.js:1)
    at firebase.js:1
    at firebase.js:1
    at t.onDataMessage_ (firebase.js:1)
    at e.onDataMessage_ (firebase.js:1)
    at e.onPrimaryMessageReceived_ (firebase.js:1)
    at e.onMessage (firebase.js:1)
    at e.appendFrame_ (firebase.js:1)
(anonymous) @ firebase.js:1
exceptionGuard @ firebase.js:1
e.callOnCompleteCallback @ firebase.js:1
(anonymous) @ firebase.js:1
(anonymous) @ firebase.js:1
t.onDataMessage_ @ firebase.js:1
e.onDataMessage_ @ firebase.js:1
e.onPrimaryMessageReceived_ @ firebase.js:1
(anonymous) @ firebase.js:1
e.appendFrame_ @ firebase.js:1
e.handleIncomingFrame @ firebase.js:1
mySock.onmessage @ firebase.js:1
```

Code example i am using:

```
let name = 'lorem'
let email = 'ipsum@test.com'
let imageUrl = 'secret_img_link'
let userId = 1231241241
firebase.database().ref('users/' + userId).set({
  username: name,
  email: email,
  profile_picture : imageUrl
})
```

If anything else is needed, ask.
I am stuck on that error and can't do anything about it.
Recreating app, does nothing.

Comment: Your code looks to be for the realtime database, not storage or firestore.

Comment: That's the only thing i can find in docs.

Comment: Check out [the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/quickstart#sample-rules). The default rules for the realtime database require the user to be authenticated.

Comment: But how do i login in JS then @AndréKool

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Ok, i found it myself how to do it.

Go to database, next to title there are 2 options:

`Cloud Firestore`,
`Realtime database`

Select Realtime database and go to rules

change rules to true.

This solved my problem.

Comment: That was the real solution to me. I spent around 5h changing libs because I thought everything at my console was right, and I couldn't figure that I shouldn't be in this new ``Cloud Firestore`` thanks to the great UX team at Firebase.

Comment: I was wondering why the real time database rules were in JSON as opposed to the OP's format..thanks to this answer, I figured it out!

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been duplicated severally. What confuses a novice here is navigating to the right place. There is cloud firestore and Real time database in your Firebase console. In this case, several people have already provided a solution. Make sure you navigate to Firebase console --> Real time database --> permissions and set the rules. But remember this is only allowed in development. Otherwise you do not want to let your database open to the public.

```
"rules": {
 ".read": true,
 ".write": true
}
```

Hope this is straightforward now for anyone facing the issue.